# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP, tried everything but not able to work around

Tags: spring-mvc, logging, log4j, tomcat7

I am getting following error, please suggest a solution

```
An error occurred at line: [31] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\nagesh.chauhan\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\AdminPanel\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [31] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\nagesh.chauhan\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\AdminPanel\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

my pom.xml file is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.beingjavaguys.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>AdminPanel</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>AdminPanel Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>Nagesh Chauhan</id>
            <email>neel4soft@gmail.com</email>
            <organization>Being Java Guys</organization>
            <organizationUrl>http://www.beingjavaguys.com</organizationUrl>
            <roles>
                <role>Java Developer</role>
            </roles>
            <timezone>+5:30</timezone>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <build>
        <finalName>${pom.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId> <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.1</version> <configuration> <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url> 
                <server>my-tomcat</server> <path>/TestsMania</path> </configuration> </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `jsp-api` is provided by your Servlet container.

Change the dependency to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You probably have a jar-hell situation.

Anton makes a good point that the method is only available since version 2.1.

Answer (score 4):

The `JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext()` method was added in JSP Spec 2.1, so v2.0 you are declaring in your POM is not enough. Besides that, you did not mark it as `provided`, so JSP API 2.0 will be packed within your webapp and will be used for compilation even if Tomcat itself already supports higher spec.

You should require at least JSP 2.1 and mark it as `provided` in your POM -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

... and use Tomcat 6 and higher ([here](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) is a list of Tomcat versions with corresponding Servlet and JSP spec version).